# Избавиться от наложения теней друг на друга

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Имеется такой пример:

```css
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 0 rgba(26, 59, 158, 0.3), 5px 0 0 rgba(26, 59, 158, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Из него можно заметить, что тени посередине накладываются друг на друга и из-за этого цвет становится 0.6, а не 0.3, как должен быть.

Вариант с уменьшением первого параметра `box-shadow` отпадает сразу.

Кто знает, как решить проблему?

**UPD.**

Корень проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD.**

Решение с добавлением отрицательного отступа для блока справа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может раздвинуть блоки или и это отпадает?

Comment: @Air, К сожалению, тоже отпадает такой вариант.

Comment: у одного из элементов отмени тень...

Comment: @Air, сейчас чуть подробнее отрисую проблему.

Comment: @Air, обновил вопрос. Проблема в том, что если задать более отрицательный отступ тени для блока справа, то появляется белый зазор между 1-ым и 2-ым блоком.

Comment: @MaximLensky, мне кажется, что нет смысла скидывать макет, пример можно воспроизвести в 2 щелчка.

Comment: @MaximLensky, всё, что в дизайне - в вопросе.

Comment: @MaximLensky, нет.

Answer (score 0):

как я вижу , здесь только 2 варианта 
1) отодвинуть блоки друг от друга дальше 
2) уменьшить прозрачность, пересекаюшихся теней, у первого блока прозрачность должна быть уменьшена слева у второго справа, первый блок можно выбрать через

```
.block:first-child
```

Comment: такой вариант не подходит, т.к. если умеьшать прозрачность пересекабщихся теней, то у продолжения тени будет меньшая прозрачность, что не заверено дизайном. Отодвигать блоки нельзя. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: последний блок у которого будет уменьшена тень, выбирается через :last-child и ему устанавливается норм прозрачность.

Comment: Вы не так поняли вопрос, просмотрите его выше, пожалуйста.